# Having trouble to parsing html with jsoup in android

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse data from this link http://www.railway.gov.bd/site/page/f8898018-00a5-4096-a803-8b533232e60c   using jsoup. This website is available in two languages BANGLA(Bangladeshi language) and English. I wanted the parse data should be in English but when the program run it always parse data in bangla language.My code is :

```
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.railway.gov.bd/site/page/f8898018-00a5-4096-     a803-8b533232e60c").get();

 Elements allTables=doc.getElementsByTag("table");

 Element table=allTables.get(0);

 Elements rows=table.getElementsByTag("tr");

    for(Element row:rows)
            {
                Elements tds=row.getElementsByTag("td");

                for(Element td:tds)
                {
                    Log.i("data", td.text());
                }
            }
```

What i wanted is that the data which is parsed should be in english. Please give me some suggestion how can i do this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having trouble fetch/parsing data from an web page for my android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356946/having-trouble-fetch-parsing-data-from-an-web-page-for-my-android-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this URL:

http://www.railway.gov.bd/site/page/f8898018-00a5-4096-a803-8b533232e60c?lang=en

(I guessed this by looking at the Javascript code on the English button.)